# Average vertical distance with hyperbola

Tags: calculus, parametric

Given an interval and a basic hyperbola function (like: $y^2 - x^2 = 1$), how would you go about finding the average vertical distance between the two hyperbola branches?

So far, I've been looking at the distance and length formulas for hyperbolas, but I'm stuck on how exactly to relate this to the average value calculations with integrals.

I think you're supposed to use the average value integral formula here, but I can't  figure out what to integrate

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your future posts. Also show us your efforts on the problem to avoid this question being highly downvoted or being closed. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) link to know how to ask a good question on this website

Comment: The average is ... infinite.

Comment: over a certain interval?

Comment: Why didn't you say it ?

Comment: I did say it - at the beginning of the question

Comment: All right. I apologize.

Comment: Don’t change your question after you’ve already accepted an answer to it. It makes the answer nonsensical. If you have a follow-up question, such as a generalization of the original question, then post a _new_ question that refers back to this one.

Comment: I don't understand why you keep trying to turn what you had (which was a halfway reasonable question that can be answered) into a nonsensical fragment of a question that is missing the vital information in the first part of the original question. Please stop doing that. It is inconsiderate to everyone here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the symmetry of the two branches with respect to the $x$ axis, just consider the average of the distance between the $x$ axis and the upper branch with equation $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ (and finaly multiply by 2) The average you are looking for is therefore obtained by considering the equivalence of two areas :

$$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+x^2} dx = M \times (b-a)$$

Explanation : On the left hand side is the area under the curve on $[a,b]$ ; on the right hand side, it is the equivalent area of rectangle with sides $[a,b]$ and $[0,M]$.

Therefore, the average length is :

$$M=\dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+x^2} dx$$

(I leave you the final calculation)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The average "height" is the area over the length of the base. You should be able to compute the area.